# Remote deploy to Tomcat other than default webapps directory

Tags: java, tomcat, continuous-integration, tomcat9

Hi i am trying to deploy my war to Tomcat via shell script.

by default it is deploying to webapps folder, but i need to deploy to a different webapps folder eg: webapps_mydirectory.

i have modified server.xml to

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps_mydirectory"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

  </Host>
```

directly copying war works, but not able to deploy remotely to webapps_mydirectory folder. i do know if webapps_mydirectory should have it own manager app. please help.

Comment: Don't you need to edit your shell script to put the file in a different folder?

Comment: Are you trying to deploy by dropping a WAR (or exploded WAR directory) in a particular place, or are you trying to use the `ant` task or `FarmWebDeployer` to deploy the application via Tomcat's deployment facilities?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to create a custom folder for apps. But it is recommended to create a configuration file into the `conf` folder for `some` application, for example `$BASE_TOMCAT_FOLDER/conf/Catalina/localhost/some.xml` with the following entry:

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/webapps_mydirectory"/>
```

Where `some` is the name of the application,`$BASE_TOMCAT_FOLDER` is the path where `Tomcat` is located,
and `/path/to/` is the path to the `webapps_mydirectory` folder.
After creating this file, you need to restart the `Tomcat service`.